# How to insert html table multiple rows data in to mysqli database

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

This is my javascript table code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var row = "";
    $(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            $('#myTable').html('');
            row ='<tr>\
            <th>\Room</th>\
            <th>\Floor</th>\
            <th>\Rent</th>\
            </td>\
            </tr>';
            row = $(row);
            $('#myTable').append(row);
            for (var i = 0; i<parseInt($(this).val()); i++) {
              var a = i+1;
              row =  '<tr>\
                    <td>'+a+'</td>\
                    <td>\
                    <select name="floor">\
                     <option value="1">0</option>\
                     <option value="2">1</option>\
                     <option value="3">2</option>\
                     <option value="3">3</option>\
                     </select>\
                    </td>\


                     <td>\
                        <input id="rent" name="rent" class="form-control required" required="required" placeholder="$" min="0" data-bind="value:replyNumber" type="text">       \
                    </td>\
                </tr>';
                row = $(row);
                $('#myTable').append(row);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my html code

```
<form action="ad-post.process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="form-group" runat="server">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="addetails">No of Rooms <sup>*</sup></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <select name ="rooms">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" ></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" >

            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="addetails"></label>

            <table id="myTable"></table>
            <div class="col-md-8" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8"><button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my ad-post.process.php code

```
require_once './class.ads.php';
$rent = floatval(getFormValues('rent'));
$floor =   getFormValues('floor');
$rooms = getFormValues('rooms');
$ad = new Ads($mysql_connection);
if ($ad->postAd($floor,$rent,$rooms)) {
    header("location:./ad-success.php?" . $ts);
    exit;
}
```

and here is my code of class.ads.php

```
public function postAd( $rent,$floor, $rooms) {
    try {
        for($i=0; $i < $rooms; $i++) { 
            $sql_insert1 = "INSERT INTO `room` (`Floor`, `rent`) 
                            VALUES "
                          . " ('{$floor}','{$rent}' )";
            $sql_insert2 = mysqli_query($this->_db, $sql_insert1);
        }

        if ($sql_insert2) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

problem with my code is whenever i am inserting data into database data of the last row is inserting into database multiple times.

Comment: Looks like your HTML is a bit of a mess. Too many `</div>` tags???

Answer (score 0):

So it took me a little bit to catch it.

**ad-post.process.php**

When you are calling the function if ($ad->postAd($floor,$rent,$rooms)) you are passing 3 variables.

```
require_once './class.ads.php';
$rent = floatval(getFormValues('rent'));
$floor =   getFormValues('floor');
$rooms = getFormValues('rooms');
$ad = new Ads($mysql_connection);
if ($ad->postAd($floor,$rent,$rooms)) {
    header("location:./ad-success.php?" . $ts);
    exit;
}
```

**class.ads.php**

When you are receiving the function call, your are accepting 4 variables, and not in the correct order.

```
function postAd($rent, , $floor, $rooms)
{
    try {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rooms; $i++) {
            $sql_insert1 = "INSERT INTO `room` (`Floor`, `rent`) VALUES "
                . "       ('{$floor}','{$rent}' )";
            $sql_insert2 = mysqli_query($this->_db, $sql_insert1);
        }

        if ($sql_insert2) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would change the class.ads.php function to look like this:

```
function postAd($floor,$rent,$rooms)
{
    try {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rooms; $i++) {
            $sql_insert1 = "INSERT INTO `room` (`Floor`, `rent`) VALUES "
                . "       ('{$floor}','{$rent}' )";
            $sql_insert2 = mysqli_query($this->_db, $sql_insert1);
        }

        if ($sql_insert2) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my mistake but this is not the problem

Comment: Hmm... could you provide me some sample results?
Like, if you select 2 rooms, fill in the form, what gets inserted into the database?
If you select 4 rooms, fill in the forms, what gets inserted into the database?

This will help me troubleshoot exactly what is happening. Also, you say it keeps getting entered into the database, like over and over again?

Comment: For e.g If I select 3 rooms then the data of all 3 rows should insert in my database

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, and the expected results, but could you elaborate on the actual results with some sample data?
Like if you select 3 rooms, then enter this data set_______, then the database shows the following data set ________. This will help troubleshoot what is happening in your code.

Comment: Like if i select 2 rooms then in two rows i have select floor 1 and rent will be 400 and in the second row i have select floor 2 and rent will be 500 then the data of these both rows should be insert into database

Comment: and when you enter those values, what actually gets saved into the database and how many times?